# Rails model behavior involving current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activemodel

Say I have three models:

```
Post
 has_many :comment
 has_many :user, through post_user

Comment
 belongs_to Post

User
 has_many :post, through post_user
```

A logged in user can create/edit ANY post or comment.

Whenever a user create/edits a post or a comment, I want to add the current_user to the post e.g. @post.users << current_user.

How can I ensure this logic without having to replicate it in each controller action? I don't want to use after_save since that would require access to the current_user in the model which won't always be true.

Comment: A side note. It may depend on your app but I don't think it's common to let a post have many users. For example, you are the author of this question, I can edit it, but I'm not the author.

Comment: Fair point, those aren't my actual models though, it's just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your associations aren't set up correctly:

Try:

```
 # Post model associations
 has_many :comments
 has_many :post_users
 has_many :users, through: :post_users

 # Comment model associations
 belongs_to :post
 belongs_to :user    

 # User model associations
 has_many :post_users 
 has_many :posts, through: :post_users   
 has_many :comments

 # PostUser model associations
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post,
```

Now in your Post controller you can do:

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
end

def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  if @post.save
    current_user.posts << @post
    redirect_to :show
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])   
end

def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
   current_user.posts << @post unless current_user.posts.include(@post)
   redirect_to :show
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Give that a try.
You should be able to implement something similar in your Comments controller to get what you need.

UPDATE:

To DRY things up a bit, why not define a method on the Post model (and something similar in the comment model) to handle creating the user association?

```
def add_user(user)
  self.users << user unless users.include(user)
end
```

then you can call that each time in the controllers wherever needed:

```
@post.add_user(current_user)
```

to replace this:

```
current_user.posts << @post unless current_user.posts.include(@post)
```

Comment: Plus you will probably want to add dependent: :destroy to the has_many :post_users lines.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I have right now, but this means I have to define this behavior in 4 places. I was wondering if their was a better way.